# Remove gutter space for a specific div only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns with each span having `30px` gutter as below. *Gutters are the white space between columns.* Gutter width seems to be between `20px` - `30px`. Let's assume it's `30px` here.

[image]

I want to remove the gutter space for a specific `div`, so that there will be no gutter space in the row. Each span will be next to each other with no gutter.

The problem is if I remove the margin `30px` (gutter) it leaves `360px` (12 * `30px`) at the end of the row.

Given that I want to remove gutter space for a specific `div` only. Let's assume that it's for `div`s which are in the `main_content` `div`.

```
div#main_content div{
  /*
 no gutter for the divs in main_content
 */
}
```

How can I remove the gutter for a specific `div` without loosing Bootstrap responsiveness and not leaving space at the end of the row?

Comment: can you tell me what's wrong with my first solution? see: http://bootply.com/61557

Comment: Bootstrap 3 introduced `row-no-gutters` in v3.4.0. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters. In this situation, only add that class to the specific row(s) you do not want to have a gutter. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254889/bootstrap-how-to-remove-the-gutter-between-columns (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**For Bootstrap 3.0 or higher, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282059/127880)**

We're only looking at class `.span1` here (one column on a 12 wide grid), but you can achieve what you want by removing the left margin from:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] { margin:0 } // line 571 of bootstrap responsive
```

Then changing `.row-fluid .span1`'s width to equal to 100% divided by 12 columns (8.3333%).

```
.row-fluid .span1 { width: 8.33334% } // line 632 of bootstrap responsive
```

You may want to do this by adding an additional class that would allow you to leave the base grid system intact:

```
.row-fluid [class*="NoGutter"] { margin-left:0 }
.row-fluid .span1NoGutter { width: 8.33334% }

<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
    <div class="span1NoGutter">1</div>
</div>
```

You could repeat this pattern for all other columns, as well:

```
.row-fluid .span2NoGutter { width:16.66667%; margin-left:0 } // 100% / 6 col
.row-fluid .span4NoGutter { width:25%; margin-left:0 } // 100% / 4 col
.row-fluid .span3NoGutter { width:33.33333%; margin-left:0 } // 100% / 3 col
or
.row-fluid .span4NoGutter { width:25% }
.row-fluid [class*="NoGutter"] { margin-left:0 }
```

*** EDIT (insisting on using the default grid)** 
If the default grid system is a requirement, it defaults to a width of 940px (the .container  and .span12 classes, that is); thus, in simplest terms, you'd want to divide 940 by 12. That equates to 12 containers 78.33333px wide.

So line 339 of bootstrap.css could be edited like so:

```
.span1 { width:78.33333px; margin-left:0 }
  or
.span1 { width:8.33334%; margin-left:0 }
// this should render at 78.333396px (78.333396 x 12 = 940.000752)
```

Comment: Nice solution, the question is about the default grid, you add fluid rows to this grid. Without media queries below 768px your columns don't stack.

Comment: This does look like a good choice. I started a similar approach and playing with it here: http://bootply.com/61110 - It looks like the width percentages still need some tweaking.

Comment: @skelly why got you span3 a width of 24.99% instead of 25%?

Comment: The widths in @-skelly's bootply are a little off, but I think the biggest reason they look "off" is that the text is aligned left. Adding text-align:center cleans that up. But like @Bass Jobsen, I don't see the benefit in 24.99% vs 25%. Did a math prob in highschool that proved .999999 == 1 anyway (wish I could remember the equation).

Comment: @BassJobsen -- Bootstrap has a fluid grid as well. I was assuming the OP was using that portion and just trying to eliminate the gutters.

Comment: When you create a custom build with gridGutterWidth=0 it does set span3 width to "24.999999999999996". So I'm not sure of why it works either but here is the new "gutterless" example: http://bootply.com/61712

Comment: For whatever reason, the OP is asking about the default grid. I personally would have started with the responsive grid. I'm trying to answer based on the OP's Q.

Answer (score 148):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Bootstrap 5 has new [gutter classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) that are specifically designed to adjust the gutter for the entire row. The gutters classes can be used responsively for each breakpoint (ie: `gx-sm-4`)

- use `g-0` for **no gutters**
- use `g-(1-5)` to adjust horizontal & vertical gutters via spacing units
- use `gy-*` to adjust vertical gutters
- use `gx-*` to adjust horizontal gutters

**Bootstrap 4 (no extra CSS needed)**

Bootstrap 4 includes a `no-gutters` class that can be applied to the entire `row`:

http://codeply.com/go/pVsGQZVVtG

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">..</div>
    <div class="col">..</div>
    <div class="col">..</div>
</div>
```

There are also new [spacing utils](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/#notation) that enable control of padding/margins. So this can be used to change the padding (gutter) for a single column (ie: `<div class="col-3 pl-0"></div>`) sets `padding-left:0;` on the column, or use `px-0` to remove both the left and right padding (x-axis).

**Bootstrap 3** (original answer)

For **Bootstrap 3**, it's much easier. Bootstrap 3 now uses padding instead of margins to create the "gutter".

```
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Then just add `no-gutter` to any rows where spacing is to be removed:

```
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-lg-1"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"><div>1</div></div>
  </div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/107708

Comment: For this to work properly you should also add `.row.no-gutter { margin-left:0;margin-right:0; }`

Comment: Other than removing the gutter, I find that reducing them makes forms more readable. I have a class for 5px and 10px. One gotcha is that nested rows need to use the same padding, or their columns will not line up. This could probably be handled in CSS if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this! I kept scratching my head on how to get rid of that gutter space. Guess I should have checked the source code, but CSS isn't my strong point. In any case, very very useful!

Comment: actually it's `.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }`

Comment: If you want gutters to only be applied to the direct descendants of the row, I would recommend changing the second set of selectors to `.row.no-gutter > [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter > [class*='col-']:not(:last-child)`.

Answer (score 5):

Update : link for TWBS 3 [getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)

---

Twitter Bootstrap offers a [customize form](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html) to download all or some components with custom configuration.

You can use this form to download a grid without gutters, and it will be responsive - you only need the grid component and the responsive ones concerning the width.

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3zCZv/1/)
[image: custom grid]

If you know a little about [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), then you can include the generated CSS in a selector of your choice.

```css
/* LESS */
.some-thing {
    /* The custom grid
      ...
    */
}
```

If not, you should add this selector in front of each rule (not that much anyway).

---

If you know LESS and use the LESS scripts to manage your styles, you might want to use directly the [Grid mixins v2 (github)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/less/mixins.less#L572)

[Grid mixins v3 (github)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.2/less/mixins/grid.less)

Answer (score 2):

The total width is calculated with the width of the elements plus the width of the margin space.  If you want to remove the margin space, that's fine, but to avoid that gap you mentioned, you also need to increase the width of the columns.

In this case, you need to increase the width of a single column by its removed margin space, which would be 30px.

So let's say your columns width is 50PX normally with 30PX margin space.  Remove the margin space and make the width 80PX.

Answer (score 1):

Example 4 columns of span3. For other span widths use new width = old width + gutter size.
Use media queries to make it responsive.

css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @media (min-width: 1200px) 
    {   
        .nogutter .span3
        {
            margin-left: 0px; width:300px;
        }   
    }
    @media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) 
    { 
        .nogutter .span3
        {
            margin-left: 0px; width:240px;
        }   
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) 
    { 
        .nogutter .span3
        {   
            margin-left: 0px; width:186px;
        }   
    }
    </style>
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row nogutter">
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

**update**:
or split a span12 div in 100/numberofcolumns % width parts floating left:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <div style="background-color:green;width:25%;float:left;">...</div>
  <div style="background-color:yellow;width:25%;float:left;">...</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;width:25%;float:left;">...</div>
  <div style="background-color:blue;width:25%;float:left;">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For both solutions see: http://bootply.com/61557

Answer (score 1):

Interesting...

Removing the gutter in Twitter Bootstrap's Default grid,
100% working.
use **g-0** class in the row it working in the format to **g-x**

```
<div class="row g-0">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
    <div class="service-product-type">
        <header>
            Rocket/Missile
        </header>
        <div class="product-serice-img-1" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="service-product-type">
        <header>
            Rocket/Missile
        </header>
        <div class="product-serice-img-2" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="service-product-type">
        <header>
            Rocket/Missile
        </header>
        <div class="product-serice-img-3" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="service-product-type">
        <header>
            Rocket/Missile
        </header>
        <div class="product-serice-img-4" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="service-product-type">
        <header>
            Rocket/Missile
        </header>
        <div class="product-serice-img-5" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="service-product-type">
        `enter code here`
        <header>
            Rocket/Missile
        </header>
        <div class="product-serice-img-6" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...

Removing the gutter in Twitter Bootstrap's Default grid, that is, 940px wide. And that the default grid has a 940px wide container and has the bootstrap-responsive.css in it's stylesheet.

If I got your question right, this is how I did it...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stackoverflow Question</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->




    <style type="text/css">
        #main_content [class*="span"] {
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 25%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
            #main_content [class*="span"] {
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 25%;
            }
        }


        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            #main_content [class*="span"] {
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            #main_content [class*="span"] {
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            }
        }

        <!-- For Visual Aid Only -->
        .bg1 {
            background-color: #C2C2C2;
        }

        .bg2 {
            background-color: #D2D2D2;
        }
    </style>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1 text-center bg1">01</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg2">02</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg1">03</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg2">04</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg1">05</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg2">06</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg1">07</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg2">08</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg1">09</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg2">10</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg1">11</div>
                <div class="span1 text-center bg2">12</div>
            </div>



            <div id="main_content">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span3 text-center bg1">1</div>
                    <div class="span3 text-center bg2">2</div>
                    <div class="span3 text-center bg1">3</div>
                    <div class="span3 text-center bg2">4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/container-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the result is..

[image]

The 4 div span with no gutter will remain spanned for Small tablet landscape (800x600). Anything size smaller than that will collapse the 4 divs and it will be stacked vertically. Of course you will have to tweak it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to remove padding and margin is with simple css.

```
<div class="header" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
.....
.....
.....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay If you want to change the gutter inside one row, but want those (first and last) inner divs to align with the grid surrounding the `.no-gutter` row, you could copy-paste-merge most answers into the following snippet:

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:first-child:not(:only-child) {
    padding-right: 0;
}
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:last-child:not(:only-child) {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(:only-child) {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

If you like to have a smaller gutter instead of completly none, just change the 0's to what you like... (eg: 5px to get 10px gutter).

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has mentioned this, to add to the no-gutter answer above which works, if you want custom spaced gutters, all you have to do is specify the value in px for the margin left and right properties, and padding left and right properties like so;

```
.row.no-gutter {
margin-left: 4px;
margin-right: 4px;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
padding-right: 4px;
padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To add to Skelly's Bootstrap 3 no-gutter answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282059/662883)

Add the following to prevent gutters on a row containing only one column (useful when using column-wrapping: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping):

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:only-child,
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:only-child
{
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to use the selector twice ... ?