# How to remove paddings from columns of all sizes on bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to remove padding from column of all sizes in Bootstrap 4? I can alter   just one class by doing `col {padding: 0;}` but that will only effect the col class. Not it's other counterparts(col-2, col-3 etc). Is there a way in css to select a range of classes? Like `col-*` would select all classes that start with `col-`. It would be helpful if there is a solution might be applicable in this situation.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove gutter space for a specific div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489307/remove-gutter-space-for-a-specific-div-only/21282059#21282059)

Comment: @ThaminduDJ It seems to work. But I do have one question. If I place the no gutters class into one row, will it affect any column nested within another row inside the previous row? Or will I have to place no gutters every time I use the row class, regardless of nesting?

Comment: @KMA Badshah I think you have to use every time, you use the row of nesting.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. You can try and find out. But according to the code segment given at the site, it will only be applied to all immediate children columns of the row

Comment: @Thamindu DJ You are correct bro.

Comment: I've tested it and @ThaminduDJ is right. The no-gutters class only applies to immediate col classes. You'll have to use no-gutters regardless of nesting in order to achieve desired affects.